# Gitlab page is stuck at pending

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I set up a `Gitlab pages` [page](http://pages.gitlab.io) a couple of days ago. It was building fine till this morning. Now it seems to be stuck at `pending` and hasn't built despite my attempts to restart it.

I checked if there is a shared runner. It currently says:

```
Available shared runners - 1
```

in the Runner section of Project Settings.

This is the .yml file.

```
pages:
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

This code was recommended in the `pages` installation guide [here](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/pages/README.html#getting-started-with-gitlab-pages).

---

I am aware that there is a similar question on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625885/gitlab-ci-builds-remains-pending), however that was resolved 4 months ago, and it seems the issue has re-emerged (at least for me).

Comment: Is this a local GitLab installation or are you using GitLab.com?

Comment: GitLab.com, however seems to be functioning fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file whose contents you've given above was called `.gitlab-ci.yml`, and your repository contained your website's HTML/CSS/JS/etc in the `master` branch, then you have probably done everything right.

That being so, what you ran into was probably this **known issue**, which is being tracked in at least two places:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/765

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/771