# How to deploy jekyll page in local gitlab server (say : ip_address:port)?

Tags: gitlab, jekyll, local, gitlab-ci

I have created a jekyll repo and i want to deploy it on local running gitlab server **localip:port**. What i did is,

- Created jekyll blog src repo as suggested [gitlab jekyll](https://gitlab.com/pages/jekyll)
- Created `.gitlab-ci.yml`
- Run a pipeline job

But it fails (always pending). I have no ideas of,

- **what should be my repo name ?** such as like **myname.gitlab.io** if gitlab running locally.
- **Then. In what url my jekyll page rendered... !**

May be I am totally wrong about it.

Comment: what is the error message of the failing job of the pipe?

Comment: @IronBishop it always shows `pending` ... :(

Comment: check you have available runners, and this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326975/gitlab-page-is-stuck-at-pending