# FATAL: Failed to start gitlab-runner: "launchctl" failed with stderr: Load failed: 5: Input/output error

Tags: macos, gitlab, continuous-integration

After installing and registering gitlab-runner, when I'm running `gitlab-runner start` I get this error message. What will be the reason for this ?

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=darwin pid=65915 revision=c1edb478 version=14.0.1
FATAL: Failed to start gitlab-runner: "launchctl" failed with stderr: Load failed: 5: Input/output error
```

Comment: I've tried all the answers, but nothing solved my issue. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 47):

I edited the `/Users/$USER/Library/LaunchAgents/gitlab-runner.plist` file and changed the location of the log files to a location writeable by my user:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/USERNAME/.gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner.out.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/USERNAME/.gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner.err.log</string>
```

Then issued a

```
launchctl unload /Users/$USER/Library/LaunchAgents/gitlab-runner.plist
launchctl load -w /Users/$USER/Library/LaunchAgents/gitlab-runner.plist
gitlab-runner stop
gitlab-runner start
gitlab-runner status
```

And the service is up and running

For more info: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28136

**EDIT:**

See also [GitLab Issue #29383](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29383) where **Brad King** wrote a single `sed` command to edit the file for you:

```
gitlab-runner install
sed -i '' "s|/usr/local/var/log/|$HOME/.gitlab-runner/|" ~/Library/LaunchAgents/gitlab-runner.plist
gitlab-runner start
```

Comment: No idea why there are no upvotes here, but this was the solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the issue for me too. Thanks!

Comment: _Brad King_ wrote a single `sed` command to edit the file for you - see [GitLab Issue #29383](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29383)

Answer (score 15):

```
gitlab-runner uninstall
gitlab-runner install
gitlab-runner start
```

fixed it for me, as stated here: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/osx.html#upgrade-the-service-file

Answer (score 15):

I installed with brew and getting same error when I tried

```sh
gitlab-runner start
```

I have to start the runner service with `brew` and it worked

```sh
brew services restart gitlab-runner
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Seeming your runner running in a non-sudo, bring the gitlab-runner daemon can't write log to the path that requires sudo permission.
For example, the path in my Mac OS "/usr/local/var/log/gitlab-runner.out.log".

Steps to redirect log output:

1. `gitlab-runner uninstall` followed by `gitlab-runner install` to get a clean "plist" as a basis.
2. Edit `/Users/<username>/Library/LaunchAgents/gitlab-runner.plist`, and find the two XML-keys containing output paths for log files. A good path is `/Users/<username>/.gitlab-runner/<log-file-name>`
3. `gitlab-runner start`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue while trying to set up gitlab-runner on an AWS macOS EC2 instance.

I was connecting `using SSH. I tried both [Manual and Homebrew installations](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/macos_setup.html) without success.

As per Homebrew [comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/115306#issuecomment-1309856085):

> Yes, as mentioned you need a gui login to use brew services

So, after many failed attempts. [I connected to the instance using the GUI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-mac-instances.html#mac-instance-vnc) and followed [Homebrew installation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/macos_setup.html). It worked flawlessly on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

I had this on an M1 Mac. I had to install the M1 specific version of the GitLab Runner: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/26561

Answer (score 0):

Check that exist directory /usr/local/var
If not, create it

Answer (score -1):

`cd ~`

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner`

`gitlub-runner start`

worked for me

Comment: @VictoriaAgafonova install brew installation of runner ,or make sure you have runner configure under group some time project runners won't work

Comment: thanks. But how to find out which settings does brew installation of gitlab-runner use? I've installed one with brew, it starts fine, but in my project's runners page i can see the note, that my registered runner was never used.. I assume, this installed runner doesnt use my -/.gitlab-runner/config.toml ...

Answer (score -1):

I got same problems. Very green in DevOps. Tried hard for make pipeline for my first pet)

```
docker run --rm -it -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register
```

Use this, it's command for register gitlab-runner in Docker.